# How to split and merge data (vectors) in Apache's Flink, without using windows

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, stream-processing

I need to split a cube of integers into vectors, perform some operation on each  vector (a simple addition say), and then merge the vectors back into a cube. The vector operations should be performed in parallel (i.e. a vector per stream). The cubes are objects that contain an ID.

I can split the cube into vectors and create a tuple using the cube ID and then use keyBy(id), and create a partition per cube's vectors. However it seems like I have to use a window of some time unit to do this. The application is very latency sensitive so I would prefer to combine the vectors as they arrive, perhaps using some kind of logical clock(I know how many vectors are in a cube), and when the last vector arrives send the reassembled cube downstream.  Is this possible in Flink?

Here's a code snippet exemplifying this idea:

```
//Stream topology..
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env =
        StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

DataStream<Cube> stream = env
    //Take cubes from collection and send downstream
    .fromCollection(cubes)
    //Split the cube(int[][][]) to vectors(int[]) and send downstream
    .flatMap(new VSplitter()) //returns tuple with id at pos 1
    .keyBy(1)
    //For each value in each vector element, add its value with one.
    .map(new MapFunction<Tuple2<CubeVector, Integer>, Tuple2<CubeVector, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<CubeVector, Integer> map(Tuple2<CubeVector, Integer> cVec) throws Exception {
            CubeVector cv = cVec.getField(0);
            cv.cubeVectorAdd(1);
            cVec.setField(cv, 0);
            return cVec;
        }
    })

    //** Merge vectors back to a cube **//

    .
    .
    .

//The cube splitter to vectors..
public static class VSplitter implements FlatMapFunction<Cube, Tuple2<CubeVector, Integer>> {
    @Override
    public void flatMap(Cube cube, Collector<Tuple2<CubeVector, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
        for (CubeVector cv : cubeVSplit(cube)) {
            //out.assignTimestamp()
            out.collect(new Tuple2<CubeVector, Integer>(cv, cube.getId()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `FlatMapFunction` which keeps appending the `CubeVectors` until it has seen enough `CubeVectors` to reconstruct a `Cube`. The following code snippet should do the trick:

```java
DataStream<Tuple2<CubeVector, Integer> input = ...

input.keyBy(1).flatMap(
    new RichFlatMapFunction<Tuple2<CubeVector, Integer>, Cube> {

        private static final ListStateDescriptor<CubeVector> cubeVectorsStateDescriptor = new ListStateDescriptor<CubeVector>(
                "cubeVectors",
                new CubeVectorTypeInformation());

        private static final ValueStateDescriptor<Integer> cubeVectorCounterDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
                "cubeVectorCounter",
                BasicTypeInfo.INT_TYPE_INFO);

        private ListState<CubeVector> cubeVectors;

        private ValueState<Integer> cubeVectorCounter;

        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) {
            cubeVectors = getRuntimeContext().getListState(cubeVectorsStateDescriptor);
            cubeVectorCounter = getRuntimeContext().getState(cubeVectorCounterDescriptor);
        }

        @Override
        public void flatMap(Tuple2<CubeVector, Integer> cubeVectorIntegerTuple2, Collector<Cube> collector) throws Exception {
            cubeVectors.add(cubeVectorIntegerTuple2.f0);
            final int oldCounterValue = cubeVectorCounter.value();

            final int newCounterValue = oldCounterValue + 1;

            if (newCounterValue == NUMBER_CUBE_VECTORS) {
                Cube cube = createCube(cubeVectors.get());

                cubeVectors.clear();
                cubeVectorCounter.update(0);

                collector.collect(cube);
            } else {
                cubeVectorCounter.update(newCounterValue);
            }
        }
    });
```